# How to display a pointer as an array, possibly of certain range

Tags: arrays, pointers, debugging, eclipse-cdt, ds-5

Is there a way to display a pointer as an array (of a certain length, or better yet, a certain range) in Eclipse-CDT's Expressions view? Specifically, using ARM Development Studio (formerly DS-5).

Searching this question brings up a few old threads, but so far I could not find a method for doing that.

Note that some old mentions point to "show as an array" selection in the context menu of the Variables view. However this is not available in my version of DS, and I am looking for this option in the Expressions view.

**Update:**
The equivalent MS Visual Studio option is to watch the expression `(ptr + offset), length`. This will show a sub array of 'length' items (of the same type as the `ptr`'s base type), starting at the `offset` item.

Comment: Better to refactor the title of the question with "How to display a pointer ...... in Eclipse CDT."

Comment: @raxetul - In SO it is customary to get that information from the tag, rather than the title. I am not disagreeing with you, but this is the common practice here.

Answer (score 1):

In Expressions View in Eclipse CDT, add a pointer and select

> Display As Array...

by right-clicking on pointer expression.

[image: Display As Array]

After clicking, Eclipse will ask you to enter the starting index and the length that you want to show.

[image: Sub array starting index and its length]

[image]

Comment: Apparently, this is not supported in ARM DS (v2019a-1)

Comment: I've tried with 2020-09 CDT. I don't think this is a debugger specific thing. (As I know only breakpoint count is related to MCU platform) Rendering variable value is only related to Eclipse component, not the transport layer of the debugger)